# Что может остановить считывание строки с помощью fgets в бинарном файле?

Tags: c

Я записываю данные из полей функцией сохранения

```
int SaveToFile(List* pHead)
{
    FILE *p;

    p=fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\source\\repos\\LabTree\\LabTree\\savablenoteimeantheuserpressedsss.dat", "wb");
    if (p == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (pHead)
    {

        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_year);
        //fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_yday); 
        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_mon);
        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_mday);
        //fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_wday);
        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_hour);
        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_min);
        fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.importance);
        //fprintf(p, "%d ", pHead->Data.time.tm_sec);
        fputs(pHead->Data.description, p);
        fputs("\n", p);
        fputs(pHead->Data.whereto, p);
        fputs("\n", p);

        pHead = pHead->Next;

    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Причина , по которой ставлю '\n' в конец - остановка считывания gets, чтобы правильно считывать в свои поля соответственно.
Я считываю информацию из бинарного файла в соответствующие поля структуры

```
    while (!feof(p))
    {
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_year);
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_mon);
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_mday);
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_hour);
//      fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_hour);
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.time.tm_min);
        fscanf(p, "%d", &info.importance);

            fgets(info.description, 100, p);

        fgets(info.whereto, 100, p);
        int i = 0;
        info.whereto[strlen(info.whereto)] = '\0';

        pnt = push(pnt, info);
    }
```

Однако , как мне кажется, из-за этого добавления символа ('\n') функция лишний раз считывает последнее-оставшееся значение и добавляет его в стек , и получается , что в стеке два одинаковых блока . Получается куда-то сдвинулся eof .Как сделать так, чтобы не происходило повторного добавления ?

Comment: уже много раз проходили - feof файл не читает. Он просто проверяет, не выставил ли кто то признак конца файла. И если предыдущее чтение дошло до конца файла, но не прочитало его, то feof об этом не узнает

Comment: Для правильного чтения данных из бинарного файла используйте `fread`, а не `fgets`. Но по сути файл у вас не бинарный, а текстовый, раз вы работаете с ним с помощью "текстовых" функций.